# Runtime error 'Could not find a part of the path' E:\

Tags: c#

I tried copy folder from flash Disk to `C:` directory. Sometimes it is running rightly, but sometimes I get an error:

> Could not find a part of the path E:\Debug\Vip

Do you have any idea about this problem? Here is my code:

```
string source_dir = "E:\\Debug\\Vip";
string destination_dir = "C:\\Vip";

if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destination_dir))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destination_dir);
}

// substring is to remove destination_dir absolute path (E:\).

// Create subdirectory structure in destination    
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(source_dir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destination_dir + dir.Substring(source_dir.Length));

}

foreach (string file_name in Directory.GetFiles(source_dir, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.Copy(file_name, destination_dir + file_name.Substring(source_dir.Length), true);
}
```

Comment: use Path.Combine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx to join two paths before creating directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to join paths.

e.g.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory( System.IO.Path.Combine(destination_dir,dir.Substring(source_dir.Length)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method to join two path before creating directory.

```
string source_dir = "E:\\Debug\\Vip";
string destination_dir = "C:\\Vip";

if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destination_dir))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destination_dir);
}

// substring is to remove destination_dir absolute path (E:\).

// Create subdirectory structure in destination    
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(source_dir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(destination_dir,dir.Substring(source_dir.Length));

}

foreach (string file_name in Directory.GetFiles(source_dir, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.Copy(file_name, Path.Combine(destination_dir, file_name.Substring(source_dir.Length), true));
}
```

I prefer to use following method to Copy all folders and files from SourcePath to  DestinationPath

```
private static void CopyAll(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
{
  string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

  Parallel.ForEach(directories, dirPath =>
  {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
  }); 

  string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

  Parallel.ForEach(files, newPath =>
  {
      File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
  }); 
}
```